# Strange String Behavior in Canvas/JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw connections between station nodes in Canvas. If I stick to the same pattern for station names ('A', 'B' etc.) there is no problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/3k4L2ky0/

But if I use both single-letter strings with multi-letter ones (e.g. 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Airport', 'Central'), Javascript seems to be treating the first letter of the longer strings as equivalent to the shorter ones: e.g. 'Airport' == 'A': 
https://jsfiddle.net/w6n0p04w/

Clearly the problem is in the function here:

```
function lookUp(sta) {
    for (n=0; n < station.length; n++){
    if (sta == station[n][0]) {
    return n;
    break;
     }
   }
}
```

What should I change? Aren't 'A' and 'Airport' both distinct strings?

Comment: Have you tried using `===` instead of just `==`?

Comment: Yup. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: The first Fiddle should be: https://jsfiddle.net/3k4L2ky0/1/

Comment: `lookUp` appears to be working as it should. I think the problem is elsewhere,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w6n0p04w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't is `lookUp`.

The problem is you are passing the first character to `lookUp` here:

`var stat = lookUp(startStat[0]);`.

Simply change that to the following and it will work as expected.

`var stat = lookUp(startStat);`

See: https://jsfiddle.net/w6n0p04w/2/

Comment: Of course! Thanks for that -- I had clearly been looking at it for too long. Nice catch.